# Spring MVC how does it intercept

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was looking at an example at this link
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/

Here the controller class says

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer.htm")
public class CustomerController{
...
}
```

Which means any request coming as "customer.htm" will be handled by this controller. But in the same example looking at the jsp's form, i dont see any action in the form. So i am confused as to how when the form is submitted, the control gets to this controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because the URL used to display the form is also mapped (with method GET) to `/customer.htm`. And the default action of a form is the URL of the page where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This clarified my doubts